# Upper bound for probability of truncated normal random variable

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, conditional-probability, upper-lower-bounds

Suppose that $X$ and $Z$ are iid with distribution ${\mathcal N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$. $X$ conditional on $d<X<+\infty$ has a truncated normal distribution with support $(d,+\infty)$. Letting $Y$ denote that random variable, its CDF is

$F(x,\mu,\sigma,d) = \dfrac{\Phi\Bigl(\dfrac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\Bigr)-\Phi\Bigl(\dfrac{d-\mu}{\sigma}\Bigr)}{1-\Phi\Bigl(\dfrac{d-\mu}{\sigma}\Bigr)}$.

I've computed $ {\rm P} (Y > c+ {\rm E}[Z\,|\, Z< d])$ and I'm trying to find an upper bound that does not depend on $d$. Any help?

\begin{align*}
{\rm P} (Y > c+ {\rm E}[Z\,|\, Z< d]) = \dfrac{\Phi\left(\dfrac{c}{\sigma}-\dfrac{\phi\Bigl(\dfrac{d-\mu}{\sigma}\Bigr)}{\Phi\Bigl(\dfrac{d-\mu}{\sigma}\Bigr)}\right)-\Phi\Bigl(\dfrac{d-\mu}{\sigma}\Bigr)}{1-\Phi\Bigl(\dfrac{d-\mu}{\sigma}\Bigr)}
\end{align*}
where $\Phi(\cdot)$ and $\phi(\cdot)$ denote the standard normal CDF and PDF respectively.

Comment: $X \mid X > d$ is not a random variable.  I think you mean $Y = X$ if $X > d$.  But what is it if $X \le d$?

Comment: $Y$ has a truncated normal distribution with support $(d,+\infty)$. I've edited the question to convey that idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$E [Z|Z<d] < \mu$, so $P(Y > c + E[Z|Z<d]) \ge P(Y > c+\mu)$.  But if $d > c+\mu$, $P(Y > c+\mu) = 1$.  So the best upper bound you can have that doesn't depend on $d$ is $1$.